# Access files in FileBag by index

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending multiple files to a Laravel backend with InertiaJS.

When I run `dd($reqeust->files)` I get

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#49 ▼
  #parameters: array:2 [▼
    "avatar_file" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#33 ▶}
    "logo_file" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#34 ▶}
  ]
}
```

How do I access these files by their index. For example I would like to be able to do something like `$request->files->logo_file`.

The reason being that that index might or might not exist and I would like to be able to rename and save it if it does.

Comment: I think if you loop through, you can get ```$file->logo_file```

Comment: @IbrahimHammed I don't think that that is viable option since, I don't know which files will actually be there.

Comment: wait, didnt `Request` has method `file()`? something like `$request->file('logo_file')` should be possible - see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads).

Answer (score 2):

In my case i solved accessing the indexes with method get on the FileBag.

In your case would be like:

```
$request->files->get('logo_file')
and 
$request->files->get('avatar_file')
```